# Discarding buffer because too big error while using Rserve

Tags: java, r, memory, buffer, rserve

I am using `Rserve` to access R scripts from within my Java code. Everything is working perfect throughout the code where I pass variables to Rscripts and get the results back. However, almost at the end of the code, where I am accessing a R script, I get the following error:

```
WARNING: discarding buffer because too big (awaiting 44617265235 bytes)
```

and the execution halts with this error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 

org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: eval failed, request status: invalid parameter
Caused by: org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: eval failed, request status: invalid parameter
```

I am not sure why and from where this error is generated and how to solve this? I found one solution on the web: https://github.com/cscheid/rserve-js/issues/7 but it did not prove very helpful. I also tried using `connection.close()` everytime after I access my R script but it did not work as well. Can someone help?

Comment: This could be a bug in the Java client, because I presume you're not actually sending 44Gb of data to Rserve. Please post the exact code that fails to [stats-rosuda-devel](https://mailman.rz.uni-augsburg.de/mailman/listinfo/stats-rosuda-devel) or open an issue on GH and we can try to trace it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to increase the maxinbuf. For example, in order to set it to 4GB, open (create a new if it doesn't exist) a file /etc/Rserv.conf (if you're on Linux or Mac) and put the following line:

```
maxinbuf 4194304
```

(the amount is in KB).

However, I see that the expected amount in your case is over 41GB, which is an unreasonable number (very unlikely that you actually pass a parameter of such size). Could you please share the code that actually causes this error (both Java and R code)?

Comment: Can you tell me how to set the maxinbuf in windows?